# jQuery-Validation-Engine - Errors in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I want to improve my forms with jQuery Validation Engine. For more accessibility, I want to put the error in a tag below the input tag.

```
<input type="text" ... >
<p class="error">Error message</p>
```

Is it possible ?

Thank you !

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Is the `p` tag already there or do you want to add it dynamicly?

Comment: Yes, see the `errorPlacement` setting: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement

Comment: Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do what you want, see [here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)
Its the jquery validation plugin allows you to customize your error messages.

eg.

```
var validator = $( "#myshowErrors" ).validate();
validator.showErrors({
  "firstname": "I know that your firstname is Pete, Pete!"
});
```

see [this](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.showErrors/)